How to Temporarily Disable Keyboard Input in a macOS Application?
I am working on a macOS application using Swift and Flutter, and I need to create a functionality to temporarily disable the keyboard input, similar to a "keyboard clean tool". I have attempted several approaches but haven't found a viable solution yet.
import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

class KeyboardServicePlugin: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
    private var isBlockingKeyboard: Bool = false

    public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
            name: "com.example.app/keyboard_service",
            binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger
        )
        let instance = KeyboardServicePlugin()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
    }

    public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        switch call.method {
            case "disableKeyboard":
                disableKeyboard()
                result(nil)
            case "enableKeyboard":
                enableKeyboard()
                result(nil)
            case "getKeyboardStatus":
                result(isBlockingKeyboard)
            case "toggleKeyboard":
                toggleKeyboard()
                result(nil)
            default:
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        }
    }

    private func disableKeyboard() {
        // I'm not sure how to disable keyboard input in macOS
    }

    private func enableKeyboard() {
         // I'm not sure how to enable keyboard input in macOS
    }

    private func toggleKeyboard() {
        if isBlockingKeyboard {
            enableKeyboard()
        } else {
            disableKeyboard()
        }
    }
}

The solution should be able to block and unblock the keyboard input programmatically within my application.

What approaches have you tried? Have you tried an event monitor?

Thanks for the suggestion, Willeke! I’ve actually tried using an event monitor to capture and filter keyboard events, but I wasn’t able to fully block the input as needed. I might be missing something in how I set up the event monitor, or perhaps I need a different method entirely to intercept and block the key events effectively. Any insights or further suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

If you have any guidance on setting that up for this use case, I’d appreciate it! Thanks again!

you can find needed solution in this project source code:
https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements
as this open-source app is also have a disable keyboard feature:


Thanks for pointing me to Karabiner-Elements!. I’ll take a closer look at how they handle disabling the keyboard and see if I can adapt it for my project. Appreciate the help!

if this answer is useful for you you able to vote it up on the left corner of the answer
